# Macro to accumulate all rows in other spreadsheets with "Yes" in one column of other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Current code is just for one sheet within a spreadsheet and the output sheet in the same spreadsheet.  There are a total of seven source sheets that the macro needs to read/receive data from and paste the rows into the last spreadsheet (Ending Vendors).

Just need to read data/rows in sheet 1, copy full rows with "Yes" in column N in sheet 1 to last sheet (Ending Vendors), then read next sheet 2, then sheet 3... copying all rows from each sheet to final sheet to indicate which vendors are no longer under contract.  Commented code is some things I attemted with no luck.

```
Sub VendorStop()

Dim Inrow As Integer       '** Record counter for rows read
Dim LastInRow As Integer   '** InRow is the current row in the Input WS
Dim LastOutRow As Integer  '** OutRow is the current row in Ending Vendors
Dim WSIn As Worksheet      '** Input Worksheet
Dim WSOut As Worksheet     '** Output WorkSheet – always Ending Vendors
Dim TempCell As String     '** Temp Var

Set WSIn = Sheets("Vendor Spend")      '** Set Input Worksheet
Set WSOut = Sheets("Ending Vendors")   '** Set Output Worksheet

Inrow = 2                 '** initialize row counter

LastInRow = WSIn.Cells(WSIn.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row      '** identify last row in Input sheet
LastOutRow = WSOut.Cells(WSOut.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   '** identify last row in Output sheet

'** Process each row in Input worksheet

    Do Until Inrow = LastInRow

'        Rows(InRow).Select
        TempCell = WSIn.Cells(Inrow, 14)

        If Trim(WSIn.Cells(Inrow, 14)) = "Yes" Then

            '** Sheets("Ending Vendors").Select
            WSIn.Range("a1:u1").Copy

            '** ActiveSheet.Paste
            WSOut.Cells(LastOutRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
        '** Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
'**  Increase Row count for input Spreadsheet
        Inrow = Inrow + 1
    Loop

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cut your code down a bit by utilizing a `For-Next` loop instead of a `Do-Until` and replacing `Copy-Paste` operations with setting the `Range` value directly. Additionally, if you're not using `TempCell` you can just remove that.

```
Sub VendorStop()

Dim Inrow As Integer       '** Record counter for rows read
Dim LastInRow As Integer   '** InRow is the current row in the Input WS
Dim LastOutRow As Integer  '** OutRow is the current row in Ending Vendors
Dim WSIn As Worksheet      '** Input Worksheet
Dim WSOut As Worksheet     '** Output WorkSheet – always Ending Vendors
Dim TempCell As String     '** Temp Var

Set WSIn = Sheets("Vendor Spend")      '** Set Input Worksheet
Set WSOut = Sheets("Ending Vendors")   '** Set Output Worksheet

LastInRow = WSIn.Cells(WSIn.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row      '** identify last row in Input sheet
LastOutRow = WSOut.Cells(WSOut.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   '** identify last row in Output sheet

'** Process each row in Input worksheet

    For Inrow = 2 To LastInRow
        TempCell = WSIn.Cells(Inrow, 14)
        If Trim(WSIn.Cells(Inrow, 14)) = "Yes" Then
            WSOut.Range("A" & LastOutRow + 1 & ":U" & LastOutRow + 1) = WSIn.Range("A" & InRow & ":U" & InRow)
            LastOutRow = LastOutRow + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the way you condensed the code; yes, TempCell was only for debugging.  How would you copy the rows from WSIn to the new sheet (WSOut) starting with first blank row in WSOut?

Comment: You've already defined `LastOutRow` as the last populated row number in `Column A` of `WSOut`. The line
`WSOut.Range("A" & LastOutRow + 1 & ":U" & LastOutRow + 1) = WSIn.Range("A" & InRow & ":U" & InRow)`
will effectively copy the values from `WSIn` at row position `InRow` to `WSOut` at row position `LastOutRow + 1` (first blank row), after which it adds 1 to `LastOutRow` so the the data isn't recursively overwritten every iteration.